# Pass events onto another view

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview

I have a situation in which I would like to place a UIView (that is not my code) on top of another UIView and have events propagated to the bottom most view.  To be more concrete I would like to place a UIView on top of a MKMapView.

I have a UIView that contains both the views (as subviews).  I would like my uiview to forward on the events from its view to both its subviews.

.h:

```
@interface MyUIView : UIView

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "MyMapView.h"

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#import "MapGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation MyMapView

MKMapView *mkMapView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    mkMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self addSubview:mkMapView];

// Create another view to place on top of the mkMapView
// This is not my view I do not control is codebase.  I would like to put it on top of the mkMapView
// and still have the mkMapView receive touch events
    UIView * otherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    otherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:otherView];

    MapGestureRecognizer *mgr = [[MapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    mgr.touchesBeganCallback = ^(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        NSLog(@"touches began=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);

        [mkMapView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    };

    mgr.touchesCancelledCallback = ^(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        NSLog(@"touches cancelled=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);

        [mkMapView touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

    };
    mgr.touchesEndedCallback = ^(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        NSLog(@"touches ended=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);

        [mkMapView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    };
    mgr.touchesMovedCallback = ^(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        NSLog(@"touches moved=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);

        [mkMapView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    };

    [self addGestureRecognizer:mgr];

    return self;
}


@end
```

I implemented my own gesture recognizer to intercept these events and I am trying to pass to intercepted events through to the mkMapView.  I see the log messages however it does not seem to pass the events through as I can make the mkmapview scroll/pan.

Answer (score 0):

The gesture recogniser works with the topmost view if another view is on top of the view with the attached gesture recogniser, the recogniser does not fire off. A quick and dirty way would be to assign the same set of recognisers  to otherView and drop them appropriately when not needed. The action need not be performed on the same view that receives the gestures so receiving the pan gestures in Otherviews and then panning the map in the background should work.

Comment: I think I confused the issue.  The gestures are getting recognized by the top level view.  Which is exactly what I am trying to do.  However when the top level view gets the gesture I want to forward that to one of my subviews.  In this case I forward it to the mkMapView [mkMapView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; , but it does not seem like its really getting forwarded.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your comments in detail, I do not believe you can pass touch events that  happen in one view to another view simply because the coordinate systems of 2 views will be different. Affine transformation applicable to image views will work but probably not the methods using UIEvents.

Comment: I don't want to give you false solutions but one thing to try is to recognise when the touches begin, move the map layer on top so you can use the methods you have coded then move the other view on top of the map view once adjustments are done.

Comment: In case you want to try it the commands are:       [self.view bringSubviewToFront:mkmapview];  and once touches end [self.view bringSubviewtofront:otherview];

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I want to be able to pass the touch events from the top level view down to all its subviews and have each subview receive the gestures/events.

Comment: If you pass an event - what the receiver can do is one of 3 methods:  Getting the Touches for an Event
– allTouches
– touchesForView:
– touchesForWindow:    in all probability, your mkmapview instance will use the [event touchesForView:self] internally  and get nil.  that is the root of your problem

Answer (score 0):

change your code to below one->

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    mkMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self addSubview:mkMapView];

    UIView * otherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    otherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:otherView];

    return self;
}

-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return mkMapView;
}
```

Comment: Good explanation.  Is there a way I can achieve what I want in a different fashion?

Comment: Problem with that solution is that I want the touch events to go to both subviews (mkMapView and otherView).  If you override hitTest only one subView will get the event, not both.  Is this possible?

Comment: pass the touchEvents to the otherView assuming it has no gestures attached. And always return mapView in hitTest. By this way, otherView will get touches and gestures of mapView will be recognised.

Comment: If you want more control check my answer in -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908871/how-to-disregard-touch-events-in-topmost-uiview-when-it-is-clear-and-a-different/21909320#21909320

Comment: Passing touch events to the bottom view is what is not working.  No matter what I try even your hit test code will not allow me to pan and scroll the map that lies beneath the top most view.  I also need the top most view to receive the touch events and gestures.  Think about it like 2 maps, one on top of the other, can both maps pan,zoom etc at the same time.